# Heroku Postgres database : connecting from outside Heroku

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku

I have added a configured postgres database add-on to a heroku app.
When I try to connect to the database outside the heroku (from my local machine) it always gives an error

```
SSL SYSCALL error: Connection reset by peer (0x00002746/10054)
```

I have tried connection from Heroku CLI as well as PGAdmin. I have tried configuring SSL mode to Require.

```
psql -h ec2-79-125-6-82.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -U d168639egmjee csjpgbglovnmah
```

Any idea how can I connect to the postgres DB added in heroku app?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if you have a workaround, please share if you have. From my findings, you might be able to get a clue by checking the logs using this command:

    heroku logs -p postgres -t --app your-app-name

But this is not available for hubby tier. If you are using a production plan then this might be a way to get useful information about the problem from heroku logs.